# Is there a way to detect in Apex Trigger if record update was started from Screen Flow or standard UI?

Tags: apex

I would like to know at the trigger level where the user initiated the record update. Was it from the Screen Flow wizard or by clicking on the record page in SF UI?
Quiddity is not helpful as it returns "Synchronous" in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

**In Salesforce, Normally You can't know the Update action is caused by GUI Input or any Flow/Trigger in UI**. But if you want a difference.. you can do one of the simple thing as like below,

- Create an Checkbox field in that object and Keep it in backend and Enable it when you do the update via Screenflow.

So that you can easily identified whether the update is really caused by Screenflow or End user by GUI based on the checkbox field value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but the checkbox should then be cleared in the trigger (be aware of recursion issues) or the flow needs to reset the check box before Finishing